# How to use translate method in view helper?

Tags: zend-framework2

Let say that we have example view helper code like this:

```
namespace Product\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class ProductType extends AbstractHelper
{

    public function __invoke($id)
    {
        return $this->translate('Super extra product'); # How to use this method here
    }
}
```

Now what it the best way to use translate in this view helper?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is translate view helper:

```
public function __invoke($id)
{
    return $this->view->translate('Super extra product');
}
```

Also you can use `ServiceManager` to do translate or other actions.
In your `Module.php` change `getViewHelperConfig` to pass `ServiceManager`:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories'=>array(
                'ProductType'=>function ($helperPluginManager){
                    return new \Product\View\Helper\ProductType($helperPluginManager->getServiceLocator());
                }
        )
    );      
}
```

Now, you can use `ServiceManager` to translate in view helper:

```
class ProductType extends AbstractHelper    
{
    protected $serviceManager;

    public function __construct($serviceManager)
    {
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    }

    public function __invoke($id)
    {
       return $this->serviceManager->get('translator')->translate('Super extra product');
    }
}
```